# Vuejs in sandbox is not automatically reflect changes in dom but others do

Tags: vue.js

I was asked this question in interview. But I could not solve it. They provided me code in codesandbox and asked me to run api but the problem is that data is not rendering in dom. In other codesandbox and newly created project render new changes but one does not. If I refresh the page then it shows latest changes but not automatically. I want to know why. Is it a silly mistake or something I am not aware of. Can someone please help me with this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-2-playground-forked-q8lu1z?file=/src/App.vue

I tried to do the same in different codesandbox and it ran.

Comment: In your sandbox the `v-for` loops over `temp` but the api result is assigned to `products`.  Changing those to match will make it work.  [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-2-playground-forked-fl8kuo?file=/src/App.vue) I changed it so the result is assigned to `temp`

Comment: the temp variable also has object data. on the hit of a button, api calls that data and store it into products variable. If I make this code in vs editor then changing variable will reflect in the dom. But here its not reflecting. You changed to products and you click on the button then you will see old data not new data. This is the problem.

This was the interview question, thats why I want to know what is the issue here.

Comment: you'll need to be much more precise with your language for me to understand what the desired functionality is.  When you say "then changing variable will reflect in the dom", this doesn't mean anything to me.  Which variable are you changing?  How are you changing it?  For precise solution I need precise problem description.  Is it a problem of combining `products` and `temp` when clicking `callmeapi`, i.e. something like `this.temp = [...this.temp, ...this.products]`?

Comment: another problem I have with your description is the fact that `callmeapi` has a bunch of commented out code.  I'm not sure what's original code, what's modified code, and what I should care or not care about.